# Is it possible in Rails to rescue from MySQL shutdown?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When running a web service and trying to stop MySql Rails first throws:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: MySQL server has gone away:...
```

Which is catch-able. But after shutdown process complete it just throws page 500 from public folder and logs this:

```
Rendered rescues/_trace (39.0ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (1.0ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Dec 30 16:59:58 +0200 2011
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect'
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `connect'
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
```

Question: Is it possible to handle or rescue this 500 error so I could have something like this:

```
rescue_from SomeGlobalError do |ex|
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { ... }
        format.all  { ... }
    end
end
```

This has already been highlighted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915792/rails-display-maintenance-page-if-no-database-connection-available) but the answer is wrong. You can't rescue this thing from controller, the guy that asks the question sad it right "it doesn't event get to controllers... it fails somewhere in :active_record"

So I'm still looking for solution. Any help guys?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `config/database.yml`:

```
reconnect: true
```

You need to add it to each envirnoment! You cant rescue `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` because its not only for lost connections or timeouts its for invalid statements,...

Comment: It will automaticly reconnect the connection and if the server is available again the application will work!

Comment: Nice. But Im asking another thing. I need to return different types of response when my Mysql service is down. When its http then its ok to return public/500.html but if its JS for example I would like to render :text => "Mysql gone away", :status => 500 or smithng like this. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Yea but you cant do this because the exception isnt specific to a refused connection! Its about an invalid statemant what can be as good as everything. I already told you!

Comment: I understand you. I can't event catch ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid when MySQL is down (only in process of shutting down).

Ok I ask it simple:
How can I avoid showing 500.html page and show something another? Maybe I would like to reutrn only head :service_unavailable and I dont need a body at all

Comment: Dude you might explain me how to react on a specific error when you cant identify this error?! You can just use a simple `begin`...`rescure ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` ... `end` construction but thats dirty.